# F# VS2019 Windows Forms

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, functional-programming, f#

I'm learning F# and I'm just trying to build Animate a pendulum program.
Here's the code:
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Animate_a_pendulum#F.23

As far as I understand, VS 2019 doesn't support WinForms in F# (maybe, I'm wrong), so I have error messages, trying to copy/paste that code:

[image]

What should I do?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please replace the image with text (too hard to read from the image). The first error probably means you are missing a package reference (and maybe the wrong SDK set in the project file: compare with a C#/VB.NET WinForms project to check).

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking to use Winforms on .NET core, you'll need to do the following in your project:

1. Open the project file (double-click on the node in Visual Studio)
2. Change the `Sdk` to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop`
3. Ensure you have this `OutputType`: `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`
4. Add the following property to the top-level `PropertyGroup`: `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`

There won't be a visual designer to use, but you should have access to the APIs.

Comment: Starting with .NET 5 you can also stick with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` and use the Target Framework Moniker `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no Winforms designer in Visual Studio 2019 for F# projects of *any* type, and <s>Winforms can only be easily accessed (as far as I know) in **.Net Framework** (**NOT .NET Core**) projects</s> they can be accessed as per @Phillip Carter's answer.

However you can still make Winforms programs easily by *manually* adding the references to your .NET Framework project, or (more easily) by manually compiling with the F# compiler, `fsc`.

- **The Fast Way**

The easiest way to do this is simply compile the source code with the F# compiler from a single source file with `fsc.exe`. The F# compiler will automatically resolve dependencies for things like `System.Windows.Forms` and a lot of other commonly used namespaces. You can also provide lots of compiler directives for requiring other resources as well.

Example using VSCode, with various extensions:
[image: VSCode example]

---

- **Another Way**

Start a new F# console .NET Framework project (don't pick .NET Core).
[image: New Project]

Right click on "References" in the Solution Explorer and click "Add Reference..."
[image: References]

Under assemblies, look for "System.Windows.Forms," select it...
[image: Select System.Windows.Forms]

And also select "System.Drawing" and then hit OK
[image: System.Drawing]

Now you have access to both of those namespaces.

Before you run the project in Visual Studio, you should replace

```
[<STAThread>]
Application.Run( new PendulumForm( Visible=true ) )
```

with

```
[<STAThread;EntryPoint>]
let main _ = 
    Application.Run( new PendulumForm( Visible=true ) )
    0
```

This way you (and VS) know where `main` actually is. It's not necessary for this small of a program to actually *run* it, but as your projects get larger VS will complain more about where things are located in your project.